# Changing all the integral symbols from the MnSymbol package, or how to get full math support with Garamond Premier Pro in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, math-operators, mathspec

I'm editing a document in which I chose the Adobe Garamond Premier Pro font as the main font.

The only *free* math font I found that *fits* with the AGPPro so far is the one from the `MnSymbol` package.

Only problem is that I hate the integral symbols from the `MnSymbol` package.

[image]

So instead I would like to use the integral symbols from the `lmodern` package or the ones from the XITS font :

[image]

I only want to change the integral symbols, but all of them as I find nothing wrong with the other large symbols from the MnSymbol... (for now).

Here's a MWE for my setup (compiled using XeLaTeX) :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}

\begin{document}
IMHO, integrals from the MnSymbols look like simple hooks...

\[
\mathscr J = \int_0^\pi{\ddot q(t)}\,\mathrm dt
\]

\[
\iint_0^{\sqrt \pi}{5}\,\mathrm dt
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know that the option `minionint` for the package `\usepackage{MinionPro}` works here. See here: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2280/shutterseleo005.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Seems like I found a better alternative for the math font to fit the main font (something I didn't know was available).

I followed [this procedure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/how-can-i-install-uarial-sty-on-a-mac) from another question in this forum (works if you're on a Mac or Linux I guess). This made available a `Garamond` math font via the `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`. This way, even if the Garamond employed is not exactly the same as AGPPro, the math *fits in beautifully*.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\begin{document}
Imho, MnSymbol integral symbols look like simple hooks.
\[
\mathscr J = \int_0^\pi{\ddot q(t)}\,\mathrm dt
\]
\[
\iint_0^{\sqrt \pi}{5}\,\mathrm dt
\]

\textsc{Petites Capitales}

\textit{\textsc{Petites Capitales Italiques}}

Quad
 
ffi ffl fft
\end{document}
```

**NOTE** Be careful to load the URW-Garamond **before** the `fontspec` package and the `\setmainfont` command if you wish to keep AGPPro's features (Swashes, Small Italic Caps and stuff).

[image]

Another alternative consists in loading the mathpazo package : `\usepackage{mathpazo}`, it uses a font **similar** to the one used by `MnSymbol` but with different integral symbols. In fact it uses the Palatino font. What's more, one can define whatever main font desired without interference (when compiled with XeLaTeX).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\begin{document}
Imho, MnSymbol integral symbols look like simple hooks.
\[
\mathscr J = \int_0^\pi{\ddot q(t)}\,\mathrm dt
\]
\[
\iint_0^{\sqrt \pi}{5}\,\mathrm dt
\]
\textsc{Petites Capitales}
\textit{\textsc{Petites Capitales Italiques}}
Quad
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

This is just an alternative because the `mathpazo` loads the Palatino font math operators, which are not exactly the same as the MnSymbol ones...

Comment: Hmmm, the `mathpazo` package loads math alphabets associated with the `Palatino` font family. AFAICT, it doesn't load the `MnSymbol` package.

Comment: @Mico Well yes, you're right. It's just that when I compared the two fonts (not the operators), at least to my eyes they look exactly equal...

Comment: @jrojasqu But they don't, e.g., all the relation symbols are clearly differentiable (smaller in `MnSymbol`).

Comment: @Manuel You're right too... Seems like I was too hasty...

Comment: @Manuel I just edited my answer, seems like I found a better solution to integrate the math using AGPPro as the main font (though maybe you already know about it).